# Email not being sent from C# using gmail a/c

Tags: c#, email, smtp

The email is not being sent from C# code using the gmail smtp settings. It is giving an error of "Server requires a Secure connection or the Client was not authenticated."

The email and password are same as used for Login..

Following is the complete code.

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("<from>","<to>");

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<email>", "<password>");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Timeout = 20000;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            mail.Body = "Test email from C# Code";
            mail.Subject = "Test Email";

            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to Send Email");

            try {
                client.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent... ");
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not send email to the mentioned recipient" + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not send Email..\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help appreciated :) -- Kind regards,

Comment: Are you using Google's 2-step-authentication? If yes, have you tried to deactivate it (only for test purposes)?

Comment: not sure about that :) .. what is 2-step authentication .. However have also tried using Live (hotmail) smtp server with their a/c but that also gives another error.

Comment: what is the error you get

Comment: 2-step-authentification is a system, where you have to approve every new hardware, which wants to login to your google account. The approvement can be done, by using secret keys, which can be generated from your smartphone.

Concerning your problem - look at my answer below... ;)

Comment: @NetStarter the error was similar to "Server requires a Secure connection or the Client was not authenticated." .. The issue has been solved however. kindly see the below answer marked correct

Comment: @AbdulAli ok thanks your problem was with the 2 step authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to swap the following lines.

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<email>", "<password>");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

You have to set the UseDedaultCredentials property at first.

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;    
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<email>", "<password>");
```

That's the way, it should work.